# Netty doesn't read string without '\n'

Tags: java, sockets, netty

There is a Socket Client in C and Socket Server in Java with Netty framework. when client sends string to server side, they send them without any delimiters, without \n or \r. and for this reason in Server side we can't get any data, because Netty need Delimiters as I know. is any way to get strings from client without delimiters? this is my Server Initializer code:

```
@Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {          
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("timeout", new ReadTimeoutHandler(30));
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new TRSServerInterfaceHandler());

    }
```

Comment: If they're sending without delimiters, don't specify a line terminator as the delimiter. Surely this is obvious? The messages must be defined in some way: what is it? Length-word prefix? Fixed length? Self-describing protocol (XML for example)?